# Resx file does not get deployed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, resx

I have a **ClassLibrary (.NetStandard 2.0)** which only contains the .resx-files which get used in more than one application.

I noticed that one of those resx-files gets not deployed so my application can not access the values for the language I need.

[image]

So I problem is that I get all files from *Dictionary* but from *MobileDictionary* only the *MobileDictionary.en* one.

I compared the properties of the different file and I noticed that the **MobileDictionary** one was set to ***Embedded resource*** and ***Copy always*** while the **Dictionary** was set to ***Embedded resource*** and ***Do not copy*** so I switched to the same settings but it didn't work.

In my UWP-Project it is not working while on Android it works fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

*Possible Build actions*

[image]

Comment: The default build action of Resx file is `PRIresource`, Please try set it as  PRIresource.

Comment: I looked up your suggestion but there was not the build action available maybe it is because it is a .NetStandard project

Comment: The Resx file will not be found if it stored in .NetStandard  class library.

Comment: Oh do you know why and which project type I should use? And any idea why one dictionary works and the other does not? Both are in the same library

Comment: I have checked [xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UsingResxLocalization/) app, and its resource stored in `NetStandard`, but it make `TranslateExtension` to translate the resource for forms xaml control. for your scenario, you could create uwp class library to store resx file.

Comment: Okay but like I said one dictionray works fine inside my uwp application but the other does not do you know what this could cause? But how would I use the uwp library without writing the same resx-file twice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Performing many testing and comparing I noticed that **even if** the .resx-file has a **default language**, I needed to have the exact same language as the default one so if my **.resx-file** is **"es" you need an en.resx-file**, 
so I added **MobileDictionary.es.resx** too and **it worked**.